# WPF: DataGrid showing validation error on all DataGridTemplateColumns

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

I have a simple standard WPF 4 DataGrid with two columns.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemDataView}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Alpha">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Alpha}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Beta">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Beta}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The data objects displayed are defined as so:

```
public class MyObject : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    [Required]
    public string Alpha { get; set; }

    public string Beta { get; set; }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Alpha); }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        yield return propertyName;
    }
}
```

i.e. Alpha must have a non-empty value, but Beta can be null.

If I add a MyObject where the Alpha value is empty, then *both* the Alpha and Beta cells are given a red border indicating a validation error. This only happens for DataGridTemplateColumns; I've tried adding a DataGridTextColumn and it doesn't get the red border. The Beta column also gets a red border if it is not bound to anything, or even if it doesn't have a control attached (e.g. DataTemplate is empty).

a) Why does this happen?

b) How can I stop it happening? I only want the red validation border on the cell with the error.

Comment: your HasErrors function returns only an evaluation of Alpha.  So the Beta cell will just mirror whatever the Alpha cell condition is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INotifyDataErrorInfo` is used to determine if there are errors. Specifically, the `HasErrors` property must be implemented to return true or false to denote if errors exist.  In your case, the `HasErrors` implementation is only looking at `Alpha`:

```
public bool HasErrors
{
    get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Alpha); }
}
```

So it will only show that there are errors if `Alpha` is null or empty.

You'll need to modify that to check both, like this:

```
public bool HasErrors
{
    get 
    {
       return !AlphaIsValid || !BetaIsValid;
    }
}

private bool AlphaIsValid
{
    get {return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Alpha);}
}

private bool BetaIsValid
{
    get {return Beta == null || Beta != "";}
}
```

Then, in `GetErrors()`, check the string that's passed in to see if it matches `Alpha` or `Beta`, and provide an error message for each, like this:

```
public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
{
    if (propertyName == nameof(Alpha) && !AlphaIsValid)
    {
        return new []{"Alpha is null or empty"};
    }
    if (propertyName == nameof(Beta)  && !BetaIsValid)
    {
        return new []{"Beta is empty"};
    }
    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

Return an empty collection if there are no errors for the property.

Currently, you're returning a value for both properties (in that you're just returning the property name back), so both are marked as having validation errors.

For Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Modify the checks on Beta to allow for null and this is a very good answer.

Comment: @PaulGibson Thanks. I overlooked that part. Answer updated.

Comment: I had oversimplified the problem, and having read your reference link I now see what the problem in my actual code is. I was using an implementation of GetErrors that return ALL validation errors if the parameter was null. The reference indicates that only entity-level errors should be returned in that case. It looks like GetErrors is called with a null parameter for any DataGridTemplateColumn, whether or not is has a binding.